# Getting 404 error while trying to log out

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using Express and Passport to create accounts and store them in a database. So far I have been able to both register accounts and log in just fine. After logging in, I click both the login and register buttons on my navbar and I'm automatically redirected to the home page which is how I'm testing to see if they work. However, when I click the log out button on my navbar I am redirected to `/users/logout` which brings up a 404 page. I have it set up in my route code to log the user out and automatically redirect to the home page when I click that button but for some reason It's not working.

`app.js`

```
// setup session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

// initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());

// use passport to deal with session
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/users", usersRouter);
```

`navbar.ejs`

```
<ul class="sidebar">
  <p>USER PANEL</p>
  <li><a href="/users/register">Register</a></li>
  <li><a href="/users/login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="/users/logout">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

`models/user.js`

```
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
```

`routes/users.js`

```
// create passport local strategy
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

// Serialize and Deserialize user
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

/// USER ROUTE ///
router.get("/register", user_controller.register);

router.get("/login", user_controller.login);

// register user in DB
router.post("/register", user_controller.register_account);

// login user
router.post("/login", user_controller.login_account);

// Logout user
router.post("/logout", user_controller.logout);

module.exports = router;
```

`controllers/userController.js`

```
exports.register = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    res.render("register");
  }
};

exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    res.render("login");
  }
};

exports.register_account = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const registerUser = await User.register(
      { username: req.body.username },
      req.body.password
    );
    if (registerUser) {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect("/register");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
};

exports.login_account = (req, res) => {
  // Create new user object
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  // Check if credentials are correct
  req.login(user, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    }
  });
};

exports.logout = function (req, res, next) {
  req.logout(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/");
  });
};
```